# How to make godot 4 3rd person camera with spring arm?

Tags: camera, gdscript, godot4

I am trying to make a 3rd person camera with spring arm in godot4. But I am a beginner in godot3D so I have no idea and all the tutorials are outdated. This is what I'm trying to do:[image]

(don't mind goofy domo square, it's just a mesh scene name)
I have a collision shape, spring arm, and a camera. And I don't know how to control the camera using code. Can anyone please help me or just paste their old third person camera 3D code here? But remember, I want a traditional third person camera. Like you can rotate it all around the player and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
CharacterBody3D
├ ... other stuff ...
└ HorizontalPivot
  └ VerticalPivot
    └ SpringArm3D
      └ Camera3D
```

Then, from code, you will rotate your `HorizontalPivot` and `VerticalPivot` (they are just `Node3D`) horizontally and vertically, respectively, based on user input (either based on mouse motion, or based on joypad axis).

You, of course, would configure the `SpringArm3D` to extend away from the `CharacterBody3D`, with a collision shape (e.g. a sphere shape), and the collision mask set appropriately to collide with the environment.

And have the `Camera3D` pointing to the `CharacterBody3D`.

---

If you need to offset the camera, I strongly recommend to add additional `Node3D`:

```
CharacterBody3D
├ ... other stuff ...
└ CameraRootOffset
  └ HorizontalPivot
    └ VerticalPivot
      └ SpringArm3D
        └ CameraLeafOffset
          └ Camera3D
```

But do not displace them. Rotate them. For example the `CameraRootOffset` can have a 15 degrees rotation, and the `CameraLeafOffset` has a -15 degrees rotation. As a result of the `SpringArm3D` this will result in the `Camera3D` going off to the side... Tweak this to get an over the shoulder view (perhaps try to place the character according to the rule of thirds).

---

How do the pivots rotate?

They take input in `_process`, with some configuration sensitivity (you can export that property so you can tweak it in the inspector):

```
var input := Input.get_axis(negative_action, positive_action) * sensitivity * delta
```

Then you update the current angle:

```
current_angle = wrapf(current_angle, -PI, PI) + input
```

Here I'm wrapping it to the range from `-PI` to `PI` so it is expressed as the shorter rotation.

Ah, but you might want to clamp it to a minimum and maximum angle for the vertical pivot (angle range which you will also want to tweak from the inspector):

```
current_angle = clampf(
    wrapf(current_angle, -PI, PI),
    deg_to_rad(min_angle),
    deg_to_rad(max_angle)
)
```

And finally set a new transform based on the angle:

```
transform.basis = Basis(
    Quaternion(axis_3D, current_angle)
)
```

Here `axis_3d` is the rotation axis (so `Vector3.UP` for the horizontal rotation, and `Vector3.RIGHT` for the vertical).